# FCM push notification with parse server

Tags: parse-platform, push-notification, parse-server

I need to add FCM push in parse server setting. Please help me.

However when sending from parse. There is some issue between parse server and FCM then.

Here is my index.js, sample code:

```
var express = require("express");
var ParseServer = require("/usr/lib/node_modules/parse-server").ParseServer;
var ParseDashboard = require("/usr/lib/node_modules/parse-dashboard");

var allowInsecureHTTP = true;

var api = new ParseServer({
  databaseURI: "mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/****",
  appId: "****",
  masterKey: "****",
  serverURL: "http://**.**.**.**:1234/parse",

  push: {
    ios: {
      pfx: "/usr/lib/node_modules/push_crt.p12",
      passphrase: "example",
      bundleId: "com.example",
      production: true
    },
    android: {
      senderId: "123456",
      apiKey: "******"
    }
  }
});

var dashboard = new ParseDashboard(
  {
    apps: [
      {
        serverURL: "http://**.**.**.**:1234/parse",
        appId: "******",
        masterKey: "******",
        appName: "MyApp"
      }
    ],
    users: [{ user: "admin", pass: "admin" }]
  },
  allowInsecureHTTP
);

var app = express();

// make the Parse Server available at /parse
app.use("/parse", api);

// make the Parse Dashboard available at /dashboard
app.use("/dashboard", dashboard);

var httpServer = require("http").createServer(app);
httpServer.listen(1234);
```

Please check and help me. How to add FCM connection inside parse server.

Comment: What exactly issue you have?

Comment: @AlexanderGutenev i want to add fcm server key in parse server.

Answer (score 0):

For the `ios` configuration, I can see 2 errors:

- `pfx` path is probably wrong and that wont work on a server cause its not relative (ie. thats specific to your local computer). Save the file in a "certs" (or whatever you wanna call it) folder where you got the nodejs code. Then update with `pfx: __dirname + '/certs/push_crt.p12'`
- `bundleId` is not the right key, this should be updated to `topic: 'com.example'`

For the `android` config, im not sure what `senderId` is for, maybe you should get rid of that, unless you are sure you need it.